# How can I use SQL's "replace" function from Propel ORM?

Tags: php, sql, propel

I have a unique field in a table, and I'd like to replace it with a new value. With SQL, I can simply [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) rather than `insert` the normal way. Can this be done in Propel without writing SQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for but accomplishes the same thing.

According to the MySQL docs, doing a REPLACE causes a DELETE and an INSERT.

So you could potentially do this:

```
$book->delete();
$book->setDeleted(false);
$book->setId(null);
$book->setNew(true);
$book->save();
```

Where book is an object you are replacing.

You can see a snippet here:

http://sandbox.propelorm.org/c8d3d29

I searched the Propel code base and didn't see any code referring to MySQL's REPLACE keyword.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but what's subtly omitted by MySQL's doc is that REPLACE works well when it comes to used foreign keys where a DELETE + INSERT will fail because of those FKs.

Comment: That's nice of them.